Sudden FPS drop in Zelda Breath of the Wild
My FPS dropped from 40/30 to 15/20 after 30 min of gameplay.
I play on Cemu. I already did everything that I could, but it’s not working. I tried the shaders, updated the drivers, but it’s not working. Does anyone know what could cause this?
My config:

Lenovo Ideal Pad 3
Ryzen 7500u
8 GB RAM

I could play with a batter graphics configuration, but I’m playing with the following right now (click images for larger versions):















Could you please use proper punctuation so your question is a little easier to read? If you put effort into your question, you can expect others to put more effort into their answers. As for your situation: did the environment change drastically after 30 minutes? Do you have to set a memory limit in the emulator manually that might need some tweaking?

Maybe or maybe not related: Sudden FPS drop in Cemu BOTW caused by unknown monster only
